# How to get information from the Android notification bar?

Tags: android, sdk, notifications

I want to make an Android app that sends a mail when i get something in my notification bar on my phone. I can´t find any information about how to check if there is something in the notification bar. Is this possible? If so, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: If you add more detail to your question (ideally including a screenshot of the notification bar) you may get more/better answers that way. Be specific in text about the Android build you're targeting, etc.

Comment: maybe but i got a short and good answer fast this way.

Comment: That's really great that you got a good answer quickly! Isn't stack overflow awesome? I bet it makes you want to make it _even better_ by improving your question so that people with that same question will find it easily. Well, I've got good news: there's nothing stopping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write [a `NotificationListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). It will be notified as notifications come and go.